# How do we add livedata to spinner in Java

Tags: java, android

How can we use livedata in spinners? I have the following:

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    LiveData<List<Site>> sites = SiteDatabase.getInstance(this).siteDao().getAllSites();

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSites);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Site>(this, 
    this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sites); //What Goes Here ? This gives Cannot Resolve Constructor Error...
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what exactly you ask, is the line of code or how to add livedata to spinner in Java

Comment: This is the code I'm trying to use....I don't know how to do it...

Comment: But what you have a compile error or you don't know what to do with variable ? Clarify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace this line

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Site>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sites);
```

with this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Site(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sites.getValue());
```

The signature for your `ArrayAdapter` is like this `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Site> objects)`. You are correctly passing the `Context` and `int` param however the last param needs to be a `List<Site>` instead of a `LiveData<List<Site>`.

Comment: Thanks however. Please see above as I updated that line.

Comment: just replace sites in constructor with sites.getValue().

Comment: Ok This works! But now I get a Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size() on the spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Make sure your sites.getValue() method does not return null or empty. Debug to make sure whether it is not null or empty.

Comment: Which means `SiteDatabase.getInstance(this).siteDao().getAllSites();` this line is not working. Check what is going wrong there. Once your `sites.getValue()` has necessary data your spinner will work fluently.